# Is it possible to create a funnel in Google Analytics, based on JavaScript events taking place on one web page?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager

We have a complex order form with multiple steps all taking place on one page. From a business analysis point of view we've been given a requirement to be able to visualise the progress of users through this form in Google Analytics as a funnel.

e.g.

1. Option on step 1 clicked
2. Option on step 2 clicked
3. Input on step 3 completed
4. Checkbox completed
5. Form submitted

I know we can add various JS events across the form to track the actions that have been taken, but I can't seem to find a way to create a funnel in GA from this. We're using GA with Google Tag Manager.

**The goal is to be able to analyse where on this form users are abandoning it, and how long they are spending on the various steps.**

Is this possible? My current research suggests that GA couldn't create funnels from events a few years ago, and that it doesn't seem possible still. I don't want to use the method of virtual page views that I have seen floating around, as this comes with too many other negative effects.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a manageable funnel report in Google Analytics, you shouldn't be using events but virtual pageviews. Anyway, if you don't want to use the latter, Google Analytics offers the *Events Flow Report* (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2521316?hl=en&ref_topic=2521315), in which you can see how users activate the different events you have configured, even if it is not strictly what you are looking for.

The alternative is to track these events in Google Analytics and create a funnel with Google Data Studio.